# Update backbone.js model with new array element

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone.js model similar to the one shown below.

```
Filters = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        title: [ ["title1", "easy"], ["title2", "hard"] ]
    }
});
```

I'm trying to add an element to the first-level array, such that the model then becomes:

```
Filters = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        title: [ ["title1", "easy"], ["title2", "hard"], ["title3", "medium"] ]
    }
});
```

The code I have right now is this:

```
function setFilters() { 
    var options = {};   

    for (var facet in facets) {
        for (var facetKey in facets[facet]) {
            if (!filterExists(facetKey)) {
                options[facetKey] = new Array(new Array(facets[facet][facetKey], "equals"));
            }
            else {
                (filters[facetKey]).push(new Array(facets[facet][facetKey], "equals"));
            }
        }
    }

    filters.set(options);
}
```

The function *filterExists* simply checks if the key "title" is present in the model. When I run this, it says that filters[facetKey] is undefined. But isn't this the first-level array I need to push my element into?

Comment: Offtopic: instead of `new Array(new Array(facets[facet][facetKey], "equals"))` why not you write the much shorter `[[ facets[facet][facetKey], "equals"]]`? Is `filters` a global variable? `filters` or `Filters`?

Comment: @biziclop yes, filters is a global variable. Thanks for the tip on the arrays.

Comment: Also `{ {"title1", "easy"}, {"title2", "hard"} }` should be `[ ["title1", "easy"], ["title2", "hard"] ]`. `{}` is for creating objects: `{ name:'Joe', city:'London' }`

Comment: @biziclop, yes I'll change that now to prevent confusion in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access model attributes with `.get()` and `.set()` functions, or directly via the `.attributes` property:

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-attributes

```
var filters = new Filters();
filters.attributes.facetKey.push( [...] );
```

OR

```
filters.set('facetKey', ( filters.get('facetKey') || []).concat([...]));
```

Anyway, here is your transformed function which may or may not work:

```
function setFilters() { 
    for (var facet in facets) {
        for (var facetKey in facets[facet]) {
            var f = [ facets[facet][facetKey], "equals" ];

            if( filterExists(facetKey)) {
            // OR: if( filters.attributes[ facetKey ]){
                filters.attributes[ facetKey ].push( f );
            }else{
                filters.attributes[ facetKey ] = [ f ];
            }
        }
    }

    // trigger change event for all attributes
    filters.set( filters.attributes );
}
```

Bonus:

```
(filters.attributes[ facetKey ] = filters.attributes[ facetKey ] || [] ).push(f);
```

Comment: but will this trigger a `change` event?

Comment: Only using `.set()` would trigger any events, directly accessing an object's property can't trigger anything (unless setters are somehow involved).

Comment: I think this is a good answer, since it accomplishes what the @kaspnord was asking, but since 'event' triggering does not automatically occur it could cause problems. For example if there are views waiting for changes to re-render themselves, etc. Maybe you should manually trigger the event after adding the element?

Comment: Thanks guys, this works! Looks like I was treating the models object as an array, which was why I couldn't access it. Also, thanks for the alternative to 'filterExists'... it's much better :)

Comment: Hi, added a one-liner way to do the `push`ing. :)

Comment: Awesome solution. Manipulating the attributes directly isn't really recommended tho.

Comment: `filters.set('facetKey', filters.get('facetKey').push(...)); // BackBone 0.9 FTW`
will not work because array.push() returns the length of the array not the array itself. you have to separate that out

Comment: @poorman: Thank you, I fixed my "solution", which I don't know how got accepted and upvoted :)